# SharePoint Online storage and sync limits

Tags: document-library, limitations, storage

It's not clear to me, after reading [SharePoint Online software boundaries and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498) (or even this [announcement](https://blogs.office.com/2014/03/14/sharepoint-online-announces-1tb-site-collections-and-unlimited-tenant-storage-scale/)) how the sync limits work.

My questions are: If I have 10,000 files, would I have to split them into 2+ document libraries, but they can both be synced to the same OneDrive for Business?

If I have 30,000 files, does that mean that I will need 6+ document libraries and I would not be able to sync all 6 to one PC via the OneDrive for Business?

> Sync limits
>
> You can sync up to 20,000 items in the OneDrive for Business library,
>   including files and folders.
>
> 5,000 items in site libraries, including files and folders.

Also, is there a way to see how much is our storage usage? (used/total)

TIA

Answer (score 2):

The linked article says:

> If you use the previous OneDrive for Business sync client
>   (Groove.exe), the sync limit per library is 20,000 items (including
>   5,000 items per team site).

If you have OneDrive for Business (onedrive.exe) [the upper limits are much higher it seems](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> **Sync** - For optimum performance, we recommend storing no more than 300,000 files in a single OneDrive or team site library. Although SharePoint Online can store 30 million documents per library, for optimum performance we recommend syncing no more than 300,000 files across all document libraries. Additionally, the same performance issues can occur if you have 300,000 items or more across all libraries you are syncing, even if you are not syncing all items in those libraries. If you use the previous OneDrive for Business sync client (Groove.exe), the sync limit per library is 20,000 items (including 5,000 items per team site).

Info about the total SharePoint Tenant used storage is found under the SharePoint administration center, e.g. https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com (requires you to be Office 365 Tenant admin).